# Batch file configuration with FTP

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I need to write a batch file command.

I already have the batch file which opens FTP taking all files to folder, and moving all files to archive folder it could be fine. But I have the problem, that when files are moving to archive folder, in that time loop, when batch moving files to archive folder, are new files generating, and those files which should be downloaded and moved to archive folder are only archived.

What I need to improve, that the when the batch starting running, it would take 1 file then archive that file, and again taking 1 file and archiving that file. It is something like loop, when finally there are no files to take, then batch file will turn off.

Attaching current batch file code, maybe someone could help? Would be great.

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
/ini=nul ^
/command ^
"open ftp://xxxxx:xxxxxxx@xxxxxx/file/file1/ -passive=0" ^
"binary" ^
"mget *.pdf \\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\" ^
"mv *.pdf /xxxxxx/file1/archive/" ^
"close" ^
"exit"`
```

Trying to improve the code of batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can first move your files to a temporary location. Download from there. And then move the files from the temporary location to the archive.

```
mv *.pdf /temporary/location
get /temporary/location/*
mv /temporary/location/* /xxxxxx/file1/archive/
```